Who is the true identity of Classic Sub-Zero in Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3?
 
In Mortal Kombat 3 (1995), the developers opted not to include all of the "ninja" characters from previous games—those who were palette swaps of each other, e.g., Scorpion, Reptile, and the "Classic" Sub-Zero. Sub-Zero (Kuai Liang) now appeared in a non-ninja form, unmasked, and served as the main Sub-Zero character up until Mortal Kombat 11 (2019). Meanwhile, Bi-Han, the original Sub-Zero, had become Noob Saibot, who was introduced as a secret character in Mortal Kombat II and became playable in Mortal Kombat 3.
However, Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3 (1995) brought back all the "ninja" characters, including the masked "Classic" Sub-Zero, whose ending in UMK3 is intriguing:


Having been killed in the first tournament, Sub-Zero somehow seems to have emerged to win the third tournament. However, upon removing his mask both the Outworld and the Earth-born warriors...
Are shocked to discover the true identity of this warrior. A warrior who has long been missing from a previous Mortal Kombat, and one who will return in the fourth tournament.

This ending suggests that Classic Sub-Zero in UMK3 is neither Bi-Han nor Kuai Liang, but a different character altogether—one who would supposedly be revealed in Mortal Kombat 4.
Adding to the confusion, a Reddit user in 2017 claimed that John Tobias, co-creator of Mortal Kombat, had tweeted that Classic Sub-Zero was Bi-Han. However, they couldn't provide the source tweet.
As someone primarily familiar with MK3 and UMK3, I'm curious about any developments in later games or official clarifications from the developers. Was Classic Sub-Zero's true identity ever confirmed in Mortal Kombat 4 or later games? Or have any of the developers officially clarified who Classic Sub-Zero really is?
